# Text Classification and Searching in Python

Tags: python, string, search, classification, distance

I am working on a small project and need some help with searching for text in strings

Lets say I have a primary string1 such as : Loan Coordinator

Lets say I have another string2 such as : Financial Student Loan Coordinator

Lets say I have another string3 such as : Loan Operator

Lets say I have another string4 such as : Coordinator

Lets say I have another string5 such as : Financial Assistant

.
.

In Python, what would be the best approarch to find all strings that have something to do with string1?
For example:

String 2 has to deal with String 1 because of the text Loan Coordinator within the String

String 3 has something to do because of the word Loan

String 4 has something to do because of the word Coordinator

String 5 has nothing to do so i dont care about this string.

2, 3, and 4 should return FOUND or something that indicates a small match is present.

..

Thanks for all assistance!

Comment: what you have tried, and also give expected input and expected output

Comment: Does "money" have to do with "loan coordinator"? How about "manager"? On the flip side, does "rdina"? I think your requirements are a bit underspecified.

Comment: @hackaholic I have not tried anything as I do not know where to start with searching a string. I am not asking for python code, just suggestions on where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set intersection. Make a set of unique words in your string to compare against. Then take the intersection with the set of words from each of the other strings. Keep any string that has a non-empty intersection.

```
>>> s1 = 'Loan Coordinator'
>>> sList = ['Financial Student Loan Coordinator', 'Loan Operator', 'Coordinator', 'Financial Assistant']

>>> unique = set(s1.split())  # unique words in string 1

>>> [i for i in sList if unique & set(i.split())]
['Financial Student Loan Coordinator', 'Loan Operator', 'Coordinator']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys


def tokenise(s):
    return set([word.lower() for word in s.split()])


def match_strings(primary, secondary):
    primary_tokens = tokenise(primary)
    secondary_tokens = tokenise(secondary)

    matches = primary_tokens.intersection(secondary_tokens)
    if matches:
        print "{} matches because of {}".format(secondary, ", ".join(matches))
    else:
        print "{} doesnt match".format(secondary)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    primary = sys.argv[1]
    secondaries = sys.argv[2:]

    for secondary in secondaries:
        match_strings(primary, secondary)
```

Running the code:

```
~/string_matcher.py "Loan Coordinator" "Financial Student Loan Coordinator" "Loan Operator" "Coordinator" "Financial Assistant"
Financial Student Loan Coordinator matches because of coordinator, loan
Loan Operator matches because of loan
Coordinator matches because of coordinator
Financial Assistant doesnt match
```